# In Microsoft Word VBA, what is the nature of the parameters for Word.Range([Start],[End])..?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Microsoft Word VBA, what is the nature of the parameters for `Range([Start],[End])`..?

Are they base-0 or base-1..? Are they supposed to be a selection range..? Or absolute character positions..? The way they operate is confusing.

The [Microsoft documentation for Document.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.range) says the following about the parameters. This implies they are absolute character positions, but that's not how they act...

```
Start  Optional   Variant   The starting character position.
End    Optional   Variant   The ending character position.
```

Here is an example of what I am doing...

Say, I have a document with simply the text `xyz`.

```
?ActiveDocument.Range(0,0) gives me a zero-length string where I expected `x`.
?ActiveDocument.Range(0,1) gives me `x` as I expected.
?ActiveDocument.Range(1,1) then gives me another zero-length string.
?Mid(ActiveDocument.Range.Text,1,1) gives me `x` and is much more familiar.
```

So it appears to me `Start` and `End` act more like a selection range, rather than absolute positions. But I still do not understand when `Start=End` why it gives a zero-length string.

It's like the values are the absolute positions of *the spaces between the characters*.

Comment: The first example on the page you link to shows that the base is zero.  I'd assume that zero = "before the first character" and 1-n are "after the n'th character"

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is not really clear about it: According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.range), `Start` and `End` defines the *starting* and *ending character position*. They are not explaining what exactly *ending character* means, but from the example they give you can conclude that the character at the ending position is *not* included:

> This example applies bold formatting to the first 10 characters in the
> active document.
> `ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=10).Bold = True`

So obviously, the range starts at index 0 and doesn't include the character at `End` (else you would get 11 characters, not 10).

This matches your test - having start and end at the same value would result in 0 characters.

Comment: Yes, that's when I realized the problem. I had substrings of `ActiveDocument.Range.Text` that were missing the last character. And I'm like wait what? It's like `Start` is base-0 and `End` is base-1. Really confusing. It's not until I was typing my OP that I realized the values are better understood if one thinks of them as the positions of the spaces between the characters, rather than the characters themselves. That's just...weird. But I guess it works.